# How to enable all checkbox when one checkbox is deselected ? using javascript

Tags: javascript

My Code works when I select one checkbox , all gets disabled. Now i want that if i uncheck this selected checkbox, all checkbox should get enabled.
Here is what i have tried

```
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '80' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 80. Statute of Liberty is in ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '153' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 153. Indias Republic day is celebrated on ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '65' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 65. Popular Language is ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '150' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 150. Girnar is located at ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '154' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 154. Largest Waterfall ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '152' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 152. Asia is an ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '139' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 139. Diamond is made up of ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '123' onclick='return(validate())'>Q- 123. Largest Desert ? </td> </tr>
```

JS: This javascript is when one selects the a checkbox , all gets disabled. I want vice versa, that when one deselects the checkbox all should get enabled

```
function validate(){

            for (i=0; i<document.myForm.check1.length; i++){
                if (document.myForm.check1[i].checked !=true){
                    document.myForm.check1[i].disabled='true';
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: This would be much easier if you used jquery or some javascript framework.

Comment: @Terror.Blade: not working that way.....

Comment: hope you have `myform` in your html

Comment: yes i do have that ...

Comment: Not exactly related, but giving all checkboxes the same name doesn't make sense, a place for radio buttons instead?

Comment: @Teemu: i can use radio button, but my requiremnt is to use checkbox

Comment: @Teemu Nothing wrong with checkbox-groups, as long as the Id and value differs. (i.e. "Check all programming languages you know from the list below")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist to use javascript instead of jQuery as this could be very simple in jQuery, please check here :

http://jsfiddle.net/CYLmn/18/

```
function validate(thisobj){
        if(thisobj.checked==true){
            for (i=0; i<document.myForm.check1.length; i++){
                if (document.myForm.check1[i].checked !=true){
                    document.myForm.check1[i].disabled='true';
                }
            }
        } else {

            for (i=0; i<document.myForm.check1.length; i++){
                document.myForm.check1[i].disabled='';
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: i have just checked the clicked checkbox checked status, if it is selected then disable all other checkboxes and if unchecked enable all checkboxes

Comment: your first if condition checks wheteher your check box is not checked......it makes all checkbox disable

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function validate(element){
        for (i=0; i<document.myForm.check1.length; i++){
            if (!(document.myForm.check1[i].checked)){
                document.myForm.check1[i].disabled=true;
            }
            if(!(element.checked)){
                document.myForm.check1[i].disabled=false;
            }
            element.disabled=false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '80' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 80. Statute of Liberty is in ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '153' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 153. Indias Republic day is celebrated on ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '65' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 65. Popular Language is ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '150' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 150. Girnar is located at ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '154' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 154. Largest Waterfall ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '152' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 152. Asia is an ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '139' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 139. Diamond is made up of ? </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '123' onclick='return(validate(this))'>Q- 123. Largest Desert ? </td> </tr>
</form>
```

Try this

In the For loop's First if condition checkes whether each element is checked , It disables the elements which are not checked.

In the second If condition, it checkes whether the clicked element is not checked and enables all elements..

and in the end it enables the clicked element.

Pretty Confusing but serves the purpose...

Comment: can u expalin from the second if condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Several things to be mentioned:

- Once you ckeck the result it is better to leave that single checkbox enabled
- You don't need to add `onclick` to all checkboxes - it is not efficient, hard to maintain and will produce behind the scenes anonymous functions for each such declaration; You may attach event to parent of all checkboxes and just check the target of the event to filter out all unrelevant elements.

Here is my solution for you:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
  <table>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '80'>Q- 80. Statute of Liberty is in ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '153'>Q- 153. Indias Republic day is celebrated on ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '65'>Q- 65. Popular Language is ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '150'>Q- 150. Girnar is located at ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '154'>Q- 154. Largest Waterfall ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '152'>Q- 152. Asia is an ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '139'>Q- 139. Diamond is made up of ? </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan='3'> <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value = '123'>Q- 123. Largest Desert ? </td> </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function listen(element, event, callback) {
  if(element.attachEvent) { // IE
    element.attachEvent('on'+event, callback);
  } else { // W3C
    element.addEventListener(event, callback);
  }
}

var form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
listen(form, 'click', function(event){
  var checkBoxes, i, checked, target;
  target = event.srcElement || event.target; // IE or W3C 
  if(target.getAttribute('name') === 'check1') {
    checkBoxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[name="check1"]');
    checked = target.checked;
    for(i=0;i<checkBoxes.length;i++) {
      checkBoxes[i].disabled = checked && checkBoxes[i] !== target;
    }
    if(checked) {
      // Validate and do something with result (target.value)
    } else {
      // Reset validation and result
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/iKiNenA/10/edit

*Note: You should place the `<script>...</script>` after the `<form>...</form>` in order to be sure that it runs after form DOM is loaded. Otherwise wrap the code with `document.onload = funciton() { ... }`*

With jQuery you can reduce your javascript code just to this:

```
$(function() {

  $('#myForm').on('click', 'input[name="check1"]', function(event) {
    $('#myForm input[name="check1"]').prop('disabled', event.target.checked);
    event.target.disabled = false;
    if(event.target.checked) {
      // Validate and do something with result (event.target.value)
    } else {
      // Reset validation and result
    }
  });

});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/iKiNenA/9/edit

*Tested on IE8+, FF, Safari, Chrome (on Mac and Windows)*